# where can i get MIME files for serving blackberry apps?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, windows-server

I had deployed my **blackberry** app and i have two files from `deliverables\Web`: those are  .**jad** and .**cod** files.  I have uploaded them to my web server.

I searched on more articles and I must install MIME files to web server so a user can download .**jad** file and setup the app on the device. I tried to solve this issue but i cannot .

So **where can i get MIME files and how can I install on windows server?**

Comment: extract the cod file , also add the jad file inside that folder and put that folder on your server. Then call that jad files path on your device's browser. so it will download and install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serve out BlackBerry apps from your own web server, you'll need to configure the MIME types for `jad` and `cod` files on your server.

For Apache's HTTP server, I use these MIME type mappings in my httpd.conf file:

```sh
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod cod
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor jad
```

To configure the .jad and .cod file MIME types in IIS, [refer to this document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  The idea is the same, though.  You need to associate `text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor` with the .jad file extension (and so on, for the .cod file extension).